# Limiting behavior of probability transition matrix $P^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

If you have a square probability transition matrix $P$ (as in a Markov process), then I understand there is a technique to finding $P^n$, although I am not entirely clear. I understand that if $P$ can be expressed as $NDN^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of the eigenvalues of $P$, then $P^n = ND^nN^{-1}$.

Are all of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ such that $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$?

If so, the limit of $P^n$ as $n$ approaches infinity would not be very interesting, either each value would collapse to 0 or approach 1.

And if the eigenvalues are not in that range, it seems the results would not be probabilities.

Am I wrong or am I misunderstanding something about the technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless $P$ happens to be symmetric it may have non-real eigenvalues, and even if symmetric it may have negative eigenvalues.
However, all eigenvalues have absolute value $\le 1$ by the Perron-Frobenius theorem.
If the Markov chain has [period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Periodicity) $k$, it will have eigenvalues that are $k$'th roots of unity.  If it is aperiodic, the only eigenvalue of absolute value $1$ is $1$.  In that case, the limit of $P^n$ as $n \to \infty$ exists.